# Joint pdf and cdf

Tags: probability

A urn contains $4$ tickets numbered "$1$", $3$ tickets numbered "$2$", $2$ tickets numbered "$3$", $1$ tickets numbered "$4$".

A student draws a tickets at random and notes the number $X$. The student then returns the ticket to the urn, and the draws again, noting the number $Y$. Find: $$W = \min(X, Y)$$

I start by finding the *PDF* and *CDF* of $X$ and $Y$ i.e $F_{x}(x)$, $f_{x}(x)$, $F_{x}(y)$, $f_{y}(y)$. The $F(w) = F_{x}(w) + F_{y}(w) - F_{x}(w)F_{y}(w)$.

Can anyone help me how to find the *PDF* and *CDF* $F_{x}(x)$, $f_{x}(x)$, $F_{x}(y)$, $f_{y}(y)$?

Comment: What is $W(w)$?  Is it a PDF?  CDF?  What?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: PDF=Probability density function CDF=Commulative distribution function and W=min(X,Y)

Comment: If $W$ is a random variable, your equation $W(w) = F_X(w) + \ldots$ makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry I edit it, it should be F(w)

Answer (score 0):

The PDF of X has P(X=1) = .4, P(X=2) = .3, P(X=3) = .2, P(X=4) = .1.
Notice that these four probabilities sum to 1 as required.

The CDF of X is an increasing step function, as follows:
$F(x) = 0,$ for $x < 1;$  $F(x) = .4,$ for $1 \le x < 2;$
$F(x) = .4 + .3 = 7,$ for $2 \le x < 3$; 
$F(x) = .9,$ for $3 \le x < 4$; $F(x) = 1.0,$ for $x \ge 4.$

Notice that $F_X(x) = F(X \le x)$, for all real x. Also notice,
because of the $\le$-signs, that when the function jumps at
points of probability 1, 2, 3, and 4, $F_X(x)$ takes the upper
value above the integer where the jump occurs.

I suggest you sketch graph. The PDF and CDF of Y are the same,
because the first-drawn ticket is removed before the second is
drawn.

The usual way to find the min of two random variables is to use
the CDFs. First, you need to notice that the min $W$ can take
any of the four values that $X$ or $Y$ can take.

Then $P(W > w) = P(X > w, Y > w) = P(X > w)P(Y > w),$ for
all $w = 1, 2, 3, 4.$ Notice that $P(X > w) = 1 - P(X \le w) = 1 - F_X(w),$ and similarly for $Y$ and $W.$ [Actually, $R_X(w) = 1 - F_X(w)$
occurs often enough that it has a name: *reliability* function;
used mainly for random variables such as yours that have no negative values.]

When you have the CDF
of $W$, look at its jump points, to deduce the PDF.

Here are a few specific cases to think about. How can you get
$W = 1?$ That happens if *either* $X = 1$ or $Y = 1.$
So $P(W = 1) = .4 + .4 - .16 = .64.$ Why must $P(W = 4) = .01?$

A brief simulation, using R statistical software, with a million performances of this 2-draw
experiment is shown below. The summary information at the 
end gives *approximate* answers for the PDF of W. (Maybe 2-place accuracy, probably not always 3.)

```
 x = sample(1:4, 10^6, rep=T, prob=c(.4, .3, .2, .1))
 y = sample(1:4, 10^6, rep=T, prob=c(.4, .3, .2, .1))
 w = pmin(x, y)
 round(table(w)/10^6, 3)
 ##  w
 ##      1     2     3     4 
 ##  0.639 0.271 0.080 0.010
```

Comment: Deleted a few word smithing comments of mine; the most important issue is that OP states that $W$ is the *minimum* of $X$ and $Y$, not the maximum.

Comment: @BrianTung: Too late in the day I guess, I really thought I read max. Will make changes. Thanks.